dealing with macros in C
macros without parenthesis is confusing me
#include <stdio.h>
#define Inverse(A) -A

int main(void)
{
    int x = 8;
    
    int y = -Inverse(x+3);
    printf("%d", y);
}

the unary negation operator in front of Inverse() is confusing me.
I thought the result of
-Inverse(x+3)
would be
--x+3 which is 10 (7+3)

How have you got 7? What is the actual result?

I get 11. Remember, macros are nothing more than text substitution. So Inverse(8+3) is -A which turns into -(8+3) --> -11. And you've thrown another negative in front of that, making it positive,,, thus, y == 11.

It's usually a good idea to put parentheses in the macro to not get surprises: #define Inverse(A) (-(A))

@yano That's not what happens. See Chris' answer.

Relevant: Seeing expanded C macros

@yano C does not automatically add parentheses to macros.  So Inverse(x+3) expands to -x+3, not -(x+3).  This is very easy to confirm. So -Inverse(x+3) effectively expands to - -x+3.  Note that it avoids creating a -- token, instead treating it as two consecutive - tokens.

@TomKarzes "it avoids creating a -- token, "--> Hmmm.  Per my tests with gcc -E,  -Inverse(x+3) becomes "- -x+3", Inverse(x+3) becomes "-x+3".  So not just effectively  " - -x + 3', but actually " - -x + 3'.  Seems the macros expansion knows when to add a leading space character.

@TedLyngmo and TomKarzes ahhhh, I see :face_palm: Glad I said the wrong thing so yall could fix me, thank youuuu

@chux Yes, I noticed that too.  I don't know if the literal space is required in the expansion, but I'm sure not creating a -- token is.

@Tom - The space is required in  a text representation. We usually say that the macros are just text replacement, but it is actually token replacement. And it doesn't combine tokens to create new ones.

@yano: Macro replacement does not operate by text substitution. Per C 2018 6.10.3 10and 6.10.3 generally, it operates by token substitution.

If we expand your macro, using gcc -E for example, we see:
int main(void)
{
    int x = 8;

    int y = - -x+3;
    printf("%d", y);
}

The - symbols are not placed together, so they are not parsed as the pre-decrement operator. Unary minus having higher precedence than addition, the two unary - operators cancel out, so the output is 11.

Macro replacement does not operate by text substitution. When a compiler analyzes C source code, it forms grammatical tokens. Each token is essentially a sequence of characters. For example, the sequence of characters e, l, s, and e form an else token, and ", a, b, c, and " form the string literal token "abc". By the time the compiler is working on macro replacement, the source code is a sequence of grammatical tokens, not a sequence of text.
In -Inverse(x+3), the tokens are -, Inverse, (, x, +, 3, and ). The compiler recognizes the macro name Inverse and identifies x, +, and 3 as the argument to the macro for its parameter A.
The list of replacement tokens for the Inverse macro defined with #define Inverse(A) -A is - and A. In these, the parameter A is replaced by the argument, so the tokens are -, x, +, and 3. Then the original tokens for the macro invocation are replaced by these tokens, so the original:

-, Inverse, (, x, +, 3, and )

becomes

-, -, x, +, and 3.

If you reconstructed these tokens into source code text, you would write something like - -x+3, not --x+3, because the former correctly represents that the - and - are separate tokens, whereas the latter puts them together. So text format is not an adequate way of representing C grammar if you concatenate tokens together with no space.
In any case, the compiler does not reconstruct source code as text. It operates on the grammatical tokens. For -, -, x, +, and 3, it parses this as an expression equivalent to (-(-x))+3. When x has the value 8, the value of this expression is (−(-8))+3, which equals 8+3, which is 11.

To understand it probably you need to understand that Macros are expanding during the precompilation before compiling the code.
For example:
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRANSLATE  "%d is not %d"

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    printf(TRANSLATE,x,y);
    return 0;
}

In this example, the compiler will replace TRANSLATE in the printf statement with whatever the macro says and then compile it. It will take the statement as it is and replace the macro TRANSLATE.
This is the main reason why macros are guarded by parentheses.
Here is another example:
#include <stdio.h>

#define INCREMENT(x)    x+1

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    // you want to print 2*(x+1) --> 12 , but you end up with 2x+1 --> 11
    printf("%d\n",2*INCREMENT(x));
}

